# F#: Breaking out of a loop

Tags: for-loop, f#

I am new to programming and F# is my first language.

I have a list of URLs that, when first accessed, either returned HTTP error 404 or experienced gateway timeout. For these URLs, I would like to try accessing them another 3 times. At the end of these 3 attempts, if a WebException error is still thrown, I will assume that the URL doesn't exist, and I will add it to a text file containing all of the invalid URLs.

Here is my code:

```
let tryAccessingAgain (url: string) (numAttempts: int) =
    async {
        for attempt = 1 to numAttempts do
            try 
                let! html = fetchHtmlAsync url
                let name = getNameFromPage html

                let id = getIdFromUrl url

                let newTextFile = File.Create(htmlDirectory + "\\" + id.ToString("00000") + " " + name.TrimEnd([|' '|]) + ".html")
                use file = new StreamWriter(newTextFile) 
                file.Write(html) 
                file.Close()
            with
                :? System.Net.WebException -> File.AppendAllText("G:\User\Invalid URLs.txt", url + "\n")
        }
```

I have tested fetchHtmlAsync, getNameFromPage and getIdFromUrl in F# Interactive. All of them work fine.

If I succeed in downloading the HTML contents of a URL without using all 3 attempts, obviously I want to break out of the for-loop immediately. My question is: How may I do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use recursion instead of the loop:

```
let rec tryAccessingAgain (url: string) (numAttempts: int) =
    async {
        if numAttempts > 0 then
            try 
                let! html = fetchHtmlAsync url
                let name = getNameFromPage html

                let id = getIdFromUrl url

                let newTextFile = File.Create(htmlDirectory + "\\" + id.ToString("00000") + " " + name.TrimEnd([|' '|]) + ".html")
                use file = new StreamWriter(newTextFile) 
                file.Write(html) 
                file.Close()
            with
            | :? System.Net.WebException -> 
                File.AppendAllText("G:\User\Invalid URLs.txt", url + "\n")
                return! tryAccessingAgain url (numAttempts-1)
        }
```

please note that I could not test it and there might be some syntax errors - sorry if

as we are at it - you might want to rewrite the logging of the invalid url like this:

```
let rec tryAccessingAgain (url: string) (numAttempts: int) =
    async {
        if numAttempts <= 0 then
            File.AppendAllText("G:\User\Invalid URLs.txt", url + "\n")
        else
            try 
                let! html = fetchHtmlAsync url
                let name = getNameFromPage html

                let id = getIdFromUrl url

                let newTextFile = File.Create(htmlDirectory + "\\" + id.ToString("00000") + " " + name.TrimEnd([|' '|]) + ".html")
                use file = new StreamWriter(newTextFile) 
                file.Write(html) 
                file.Close()
            with
            | :? System.Net.WebException -> 
                return! tryAccessingAgain url (numAttempts-1)
        }
```

this way it will only be logged once the attempts where all made